# Can anyone tell me what 'fb:admins' could not be parsed as type 'fbid' means?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am doing my best to set up open graph on my website.

It's all working ok and looking good on Facebook, but I'm getting this error message on my site:

> Object at URL 'http://www.thesocialnetworkingacademy.com' of type
>   'website' is invalid because the given value '159229554128788' for
>   property 'fb:admins' could not be parsed as type 'fbid'.

Can anyone tell me in fairly basic terms what I need to do to fix that?

Answer (score 28):

Your ID looks like a page ID rather than an admin ID. You need to supply the user ID of one or more admins for this page, or switch to an `fb:app_id` instead of an `fb:admin` meta tag.

If you wish to stick with the `fb:admin` approach you can enter your Facebook username rather than the numeric ID, which is probably easier to debug and manage, you can find your user name on your profile page in the page URL eg if your page is `facebook.com/johndoe` then your username is `johndoe`. If you want to get your numeric ID for any reason you can find it by visiting: http://graph.facebook.com/johndoe

You can then check that this is all working by using the Facebook debugger to test your site: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Using the debugger is the best way to test it - Facebook will take ages to update it's cache of your pages, so you won't see the results of any changes you make for days otherwise.

Comment: try http://graph.facebook.com/gbirbilis for example to see how that JSON data for the user look like, since the johndoe above is dummy and will return error

Comment: UPDATE: maybe Facebook changed something (again) there, although I'm logged-in in Facebook, I see the same error if I try that URL

Answer (score 7):

`fb:admins` has to be a user ID. This is telling you that the `fb:admins` value isn't a user ID. You need to put your user ID in there, or use an app ID with `fb:app_id`

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.

You need an APP ID for that to work. A website is not an app. You must go to https://developers.facebook.com/apps and create a new APP. After the creation you will recieve an APPID. That is the id that you need.

Answer (score 2):

You can use multiple admin ids AND also an app id if you wish at the same time

```html
<meta property='fb:admins' content='5555555'>
<meta property='fb:admins' content='7777777'>

<meta property='fb:app_id' content='888777555555'>
```

can find admin id by going to the opengraph page for a user, e.g.
http://graph.facebook.com/gbirbilis

can find app id by going to
https://developers.facebook.com/apps

Comment: "error": {
      "message": "(#803) Cannot query users by their username (gbirbilis)",

Comment: maybe you need to be THAT specific user to query? try your own FB username (or numeric id if you haven't set up a username)

Answer (score 1):

In fact, lots of websites use fb_appid rather than fb_admins, like this [mac video converter](http://www.mac-videoconverter.com) site.

If you want to get your fb_admins ID, [this](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/) page may help you

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the problem was passing the app_id and admin_id like this:

```
<meta content='{5555555}' property='fb:admins'>
<meta content='{555555555555}' property='fb:app_id'>
```

And it should be like this:

```
<meta content='5555555' property='fb:admins'>
<meta content='555555555555' property='fb:app_id'>
```